# Document root not exists?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I need some help figuring why apache tells me that my document root does not exists.

My document root is `/home/user/Documents/Git/site/index.html`... It is there!

My vhost looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/Documents/Git/site/index.html
    ErrorLog /home/user/Documents/Git/site/error.log
    <Directory /home/user/Documents/Git/site>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Permissions are 775 for Git and its subfolders and files and in my hosts 127.0.0.1 site.com

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note too that you can also get help setting up servers (including Apache) at https://serverfault.com/ - that site is not Ubuntu-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DocumentRoot` should refer to the *directory* within which all your files are located, not to any particular *file*.

What's happening here is that you've specified `/home/user/Documents/Git/site/index.html` as your document root, so Apache is pre-pending this string to any path requested from it.

So for example if you request `http://site.com/`, Apache will look for a directory called `/home/user/Documents/Git/site/index.html/` on your system then look for an index file inside that.  But `index.html` is not a directory so this is failing.

Try removing the `/index.html` from the end of `DocumentRoot`.